# Deja-dup Restore failed

Tags: deja-dup, restore

I've already read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473124/extract-duplicity-files-manually) and [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159329).

I even tried to mess around with gpg to change the pass phrase. I was unsuccessful, so I can't manually restore. I am running a clean install of Trusty Tahr, and I am trying to restore my backups from my previous version of Ubuntu. When I try to restore from Deja-Dup I get this error:

http://picpaste.com/error-x1LHCWhK.png

I must have read a dozen threads discussing this issue, and any solution I try is unsuccessful. SO far I am disappointed overall with Ubuntu. I have had nothing but problems since I first installed it some weeks ago.

Please help me restore my files, I have some important code I am working on there.

Comment: @Pabi do you know of anything I can do to fix this? I am seriously considering migrating to Kubuntu or another distro