# Can I search Deja-Dup backup for a filename?

Tags: nautilus, backup, deja-dup

Sorry in advance if this question happens to be of a naïve sort.

I know that recovering files in Déjà-Dup is pretty straightforward: simply go the the directory where the file used to be and  (in Nautilus)  do "File => Restore Missing Files".

But what if **I do not know the directory** where the file used to reside? Can I search for the filename in Déjà-dup?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/332914/15811 ?

Comment: Yes, thank you @Rinzwind. This solved my problem. Since that post covers other themes in addition to the one I've raised, I have added below an explicit answer to my question, in hope to help less experienced users as myself.

Comment: @OgDeSouza, Would you accept your own answer as it is the one that works for you.

Comment: @Sneetsher, sure! I did try it and it worked well for me. I had forgotten to click on the "accept it" icon. It is done now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple solution is to use duplicity (on which Déjà-dup sits) and produce a list of files in the backup:

```
duplicity list-current-files --no-encryption --time <timestring>  target > list.txt
```

where "timestring" is given, according to man duplicity, as:

> The acceptible time strings are intervals (like "3D64s"), w3-datetime
>   strings, like "2002-04-26T04:22:01-07:00" (strings like
>   "2002-04-26T04:22:01" are also acceptable - duplicity will use the
>   current time zone), or ordinary dates like 2/4/1997 or 2001-04-23
>   (various combinations are acceptable, but the month always precedes
>   the day).

and "target" is the path to the directory where your backup is.

In my case the full command was:

```
duplicity list-current-files --no-encryption --time 3D file://mybackup > list.txt
```

After this, you can open "list.txt" in any text editor and search for the filename.

If you want something more elaborated, have a look on https://askubuntu.com/a/486458/213084

Comment: And how do you determine `target` when only using Déjà Dup?

Comment: @Andy: the target in Dejà Dup is set up when you start using it for the first time as 'Storage Location'.  Have a look on https://www.linux.com/learn/total-system-backup-and-recall-deja-dup

Comment: I do know that, but in CLI you don't have a fancy dropdown to select S3, and a key manager. You'd need some URL I guess.

Comment: how do things change when deja-dup is installed as a snap application?