# How to get a date range for Deja-Dup / Duplicity backup?

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup, duplicity

I'm using [TimeShift](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=timeshift) as recommended for system backup. It's worked so well I've been donating to the project. I'm using Deja-Dup and Duplicity for backing up all user files (the /home directory) to remote google drive.

It took me a while to get `deja-dup` and `duplicity` configured for remote only backups, via `gnome-online-accounts` to Google Drive. So finally after getting it set up correctly, I need to use it. I right-click in my home dir, and select "Restore missing files..." And then I only get the latest backup results to choose from. How can we choose from a date farther back?

Comment: Open `Backups` (deja-dup) and click the `Restore...` button. Select the location of the backup files, etc.

Comment: does that initiate a full restoration of all files listed for backup?

Comment: i went thru that and it wouldn't let me select specific file or foler to restore

Comment: If for whatever reason, you have a problem after trying to restore with the “Restore files to original locations” option, try restoring again to a temporary directory and moving your files to where they belong.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/473124/extract-duplicity-files-manually